# how to create custom modal overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Updated :** [JsFiddle Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/U7wqE/3/)

I have a hidden div .I shows it on an event and i am using [Jquery Flippy plugin](http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/) to rotate this div when it open (as a popup). I just want to make modal overlay for background when popup shows. Means no one can click in background untill the popup disappear. Cant use jquery dialog.

Background should be blur and no event happen on background.but When popup div disappear then everything should work normal. ask for any clearification if u need.Thanks!

> **update : **button 'click me' and all other elements should not be clicked when div is open.`<>`

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: i tried putting some css,but it cant prevent the events to happen on background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `div class="modalcover"` element as a last element in a document, then create a CSS class like below:

```
.modalcover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.0;
    z-index = 10000;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: none;
}
```

You may need to fit `z-index` to other zIndexes in your page. When you need the cover, just set its `display: block`.

Comment: i have already tried this. only what i want to disable events on background page when div is visible. how to do this.

Comment: What events you are getting? This prevents the most of mouse interaction with the page. Though the tabbing through elements will still work. You can also add `#modalcover.onmouseover=#dialog.focus();`

Comment: Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVZgh/). If there's for example intervals going on, they should be cancelled. Only really modal dialog can be created with [`showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a modal DIV with position fixed to be displayed when you popup shows up and hide it when your popup disappears

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 0.6;
        display: none;
        z-index: 100; /* play with this param to show the modal behind the popup and above the page content */
    }
</style>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function() {

    function Modal() {
        this.$el = $('<div class="modal" />');
        $('body').append(this.$el);
        this.$el.on('click', this.preventEvent.bind(this));

        $(window).on('resize', this.resizeModal.bind(this));
    }

    Modal.prototype.show = function() {
        this.$el.css('width', $(window).width() + 'px');
        this.$el.css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
        this.$el.show();
    }

    Modal.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.$el.hide();
    }

    Modal.prototype.resizeModal = function() {
        this.$el.css('width', $(window).width() + 'px');
        this.$el.css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
    }

    // prevent background event
    Modal.prototype.preventEvent = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    var modal = new Modal();

    // when you are showing your popup - modal.show();
    // when you are hiding your popup - modal.hide();

});
```

Comment: it will not prevent the events to happen on background.I have created modal dialog but want to disable events on background

Comment: Edited and added preventing event

Comment: If this is didn't what you've mean, may I ask for clearifications? :)